# How to export loadrunner analysis data into excel automatically?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to implement the functionality where every time I execute performance test on loadrunner, it will automatically export the results into excel. Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

See templates in analysis.   You will set your LoadRunner instance to automatically run analysis at the end of your test, which will invoke your template which may/may not involve export of data to various formats.

What does excel "buy you" in this case?

Comment: I have tried that way but that can only generate template in Loadrunner Analysis itself. It'll not export data into excel sheet automatically. I am running multiple tests in a day so I want to store data somewhere at single place so that I can compare all the results at later stage. But currently I am doing it manually, So I need to find some way so that I can store all the results in single location. If you know the way to export data into db somehow than please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: cross scenario analysis

Comment: Use SQL Server as the datastore for your analysis data.

Comment: Both covered in documentation